# Widgets in JTable cells

Tags: java, swing, editor, jtable, renderer

Widgets in `JTable` columns are expected to be not distinguishable from normal ones, right? There seems to be behavioral difference, take [Swing documentation example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) and move mouse over checkboxes in the *Vegetarian* column... They don't react at all. I understand that those are just widget surrogates, so highlighting has to be done manually, so how would I fix this? I tried `widget.requestFocusInWindow();`
in `mouseMoved()` for the surrogate widget event handler without success. Any other workaround?

Comment: What do you want the mouse-over gesture to do?

Comment: Max got it right: it's rollover (or lack of thereof) which makes widgets in the table to appear dead. If JPanel is genuine container of widgets, why JTable and JTree are not?

Comment: Good follow-on question; I've elaborated [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13314087/230513).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create your own cell renderer that applies a rollover effect. Then, add a mouse listener that tracks the mouse movement and repaints the relevant cells. You need to apply the effect to the current cell under the cursor and clear the previous cell.

Below is a short example that demonstrates this approach on a checkbox renderer. The example extends default `BooleanRenderer`. The only change is `getModel().setRollover(...)` in `getTableCellRendererComponent()`.

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.plaf.UIResource;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class TableRolloverDemo {
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TableRolloverDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final JTable table = new JTable();

        final DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][] {
                { false }, { false }, { true }, { true } },
                new Object[] { "Column" }) {
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return Boolean.class;
            }
        };

        RolloverMouseAdapter rolloverAdapter = new RolloverMouseAdapter(table);
        RolloverBooleanRenderer renderer = new RolloverBooleanRenderer(rolloverAdapter);

        table.addMouseListener(rolloverAdapter);
        table.addMouseMotionListener(rolloverAdapter);

        table.setDefaultRenderer(Boolean.class, renderer);
        table.setModel(model);

        frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    static class RolloverMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {
        private int row = -1;
        private int column = -1;
        private JTable table;

        public RolloverMouseAdapter(JTable table) {
            this.table = table;
        }

        public boolean isRolloverCell(int row, int column) {
            return this.row == row && this.column == column;
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            int lastRow = row;
            int lastColumn = column;

            row = table.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
            column = table.columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());

            if (row == lastRow && column == lastColumn)
                return;

            if (row >= 0 && column >= 0) {
                table.repaint(table.getCellRect(row, column, false));
            }
            if (lastRow >= 0 && lastColumn >= 0) {
                table.repaint(table.getCellRect(lastRow, lastColumn, false));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            if (row >= 0 && column >= 0) {
                table.repaint(table.getCellRect(row, column, false));
            }
            row = column = -1;
        }

    }

    static class RolloverBooleanRenderer extends JCheckBox implements
            TableCellRenderer, UIResource {
        private static final Border noFocusBorder = new EmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1);
        private RolloverMouseAdapter adapter;

        public RolloverBooleanRenderer(RolloverMouseAdapter adapter) {
            super();
            this.adapter = adapter;
            setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            setBorderPainted(true);
        }

        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
                Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,
                int column) {

            getModel().setRollover(adapter.isRolloverCell(row, column));

            if (isSelected) {
                setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
                super.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
            } else {
                setForeground(table.getForeground());
                setBackground(table.getBackground());
            }
            setSelected((value != null && ((Boolean) value).booleanValue()));

            if (hasFocus) {
                setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("Table.focusCellHighlightBorder"));
            } else {
                setBorder(noFocusBorder);
            }

            return this;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: [rollover is big B.S.](http://aephyr.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/), have to create a bunch of methods, or Substance has implemented too (inc. funny gliterring for plain JComponents)

Comment: +1 interestingly, this indeed does work :-) And probably can be added to SwingX quite easily (per-cell rollover support and component adapter already available). Thanks for the idea! @Tegiri Nenashi - probably don't want the rollover visuals if the cell is not editable, or do we?

Answer (score 3):

> It's rollover (or lack of thereof) which makes widgets in the table to appear dead. If `JPanel` is genuine container of widgets, why `JTable` and `JTree` are not?

Both `JTable` and `JTree` use the [flyweight pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) for rendering. The [default renderer & editor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) have no intrinsic mouse-over behavior. You have to supply the desired behavior yourself, as @Max [shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13302801/230513).

Comment: Also consider adding tool tips to the renderer.

Answer (score 0):

Jtable dont put real components into cells. They only use the component's paint methods to render the cell content.

Comment: That was fine design decision at the time, although today memory is plentiful. If we had real widgets in JTable and JTree while JTable and JTree served merely as sophisticated layout managers, problems like I have described would have never arisen. One interesting problem is if Swing can optimize this hypothetical naive aggregation of widgets to save memory footprint.