# Rollover effect for buttons in a table?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, jbutton

I can add buttons to a table with `TableCellRender`, but those buttons look different from normal buttons, e.g., when the mouse is over, there's no rollover effect. Anyone know how to make buttons in a table look and feel the same as normal buttons?

Comment: A cell renderer is a static representation of the component.  It is not a live component, try taking a look at [Table Button Column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/)

Comment: Any Solutions? ... stumbled upon the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Short example provide in link which demonstrates approach on a checkbox renderer. The example extends default BooleanRenderer. The only change is getModel().setRollover(...) in `getTableCellRendererComponent()`

[Rollover Effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13300869/widgets-in-jtable-cells)  in JTable Checkbox.

Hope this link help you to achieve rollover effect by implementing for your Button in Jtable.

Comment: This can only partly solve the button issue. In Windows 7, if you look carefully, you can see that a button is continuously repainting itself, and I don't think a mouse listener can achieve this.